# contentdiveditable absolute div in div

Tags: javascript, firefox, contenteditable

I want to edit an absolute positioned DIV which is located within a contenteditable DIV. This works great with IE, Chrome, Safari and Opera, but unfortunately not in Firefox.

This is the code:

```
<DIV contenteditable="true"
style="border:1px solid #F00; width:220px; height:220px;">
<DIV>
<P>DIV 1, editable</P>
</DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute; left: 20px; top: 50px;">
<P>DIV 2, not editable in FF !?</P>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

I already did a unsuccessful try in http://jsfiddle.net/Jf54f/4/

Is this a bug? Does someone have a workaround? Thank's in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `position:relative` on the editable element, so that the positioned div is considered to be inside it.. (*most likely a bug in the implementation*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Jf54f/8/

Comment: Perfekt, that works. Your solution solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well you should not set contenteditable="true" try just contenteditable. The term  just without any value,  you can add values like "plain -text-only" for chrome and IE because they allow formatting with ctrl+b and all.

```
<DIV contenteditable id="">
```

**Though as my friend here said, it works in all browsers.** I tried too, it does.

Comment: Not according to the w3c specs. true/false is what it accepts.. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/editing.html#contenteditable0

Comment: But firefox atleast till version 12 doesnot support the values of div, so I check the browser and version befor setting this attribute.

Comment: according to MDN it is supported since v3.5 of firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: I have no idea... but it doesn't work with my firefox too. contenteditable works.but when I tried to add the plain text only to prevent chrome from allowing formatting, it din work in firefox anymore. So I prefer direct.

Comment: `contenteditable` is not a boolean attribute. However, omitting the value is equivalent to using the empty string as a value, which in turn is specified to be equivalent to `true` for `contenteditable`, so `<div contenteditable></div>` and `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` have exactly the same effect (including in Firefox back to version 3.0).

Answer (score 1):

removing `contenteditable="true"` from the main `div` and adding it to the two inner divs worked fine.

check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/Jf54f/10/